# How to manage file name in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a string and it's  going to be a filename . So i want to check if there is a special characters that i'm going to replace them so i won't be a problem when i'm going to create the file . is it a good practice to replace them with "_" ?
i' used this is it correct ? is there other characters excepts alphabet and number can be used on file name ? Which characters should I avoid in file names

```
String filename = ch.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9]'), '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of allowed filename characters depends on the underlying filesystem. On (most) Unix, anything except `/` and `\0` is allowed. On Windows, the rules get weird. For example, you (usually) can't end a filename with a period; you can't name a file `NUL`, etc.

Other considerations: It would be confusing to allow spaces at the beginning/end of a filename. Spaces within a filename break certain tools (looking at you, `make`). Is your filesystem case-sensitive or case-preserving? Does it have a maximum filename length?

> Which characters should I avoid in file names?

Wrong question. Do you have a particular *need* to allow "unusual" characters in filenames?

If these are machine-generated names, just do what you're doing (I prefer hyphens, but that's a stylistic decision). If these are user-generated filenames, just try saving the file -- if it fails, get the user to choose another name.

**tl;dr:** use URL-safe characters: `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+`.